# Canon 1000D SD card maximum

Tags: canon, canon-1000d, limited-space, microsd

#### What are the max parameters of an SD card for the Canon 1000D?

Some sources say it can read up to 16GB, other say 8GB is the max, other say they run into the problems with 32GB. (Many also outline the technical aspect of loosing a lot of photos, when the card fails).

#### Is there a problem with a class 10 SD card?

I read that class 6 is okay, but no mention of class 10.

#### References:

[Can 1000 D accept 16 or 32 GB SD cards](http://photocamel.com/forum/canon-forum/102247-can-1000-d-accept-16-32-gb-sd-cards.html)
[What's the most appropriate memory card for 1000D](http://photography-on-the.net/forum/showthread.php?t=1067940)
[SD card size for EOS 1000D](http://stargazerslounge.com/topic/73169-sd-card-size-for-eos-1000d/)
[SD-Card speed limit for Canon EOS 1000D?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/9846/sd-card-speed-limit-for-canon-eos-1000d)
[Max Memory Limit/Capacity for Canon Rebel XS 1000D](http://www.dpreview.com/forums/thread/2853211)

Comment: General advice: Capacity can be an issue (especially when a new larger size exceeds the previous standard), but it's always okay to use a faster class in a device which can't take advantage of the speed.

Comment: @sumid That's because the camera is called the 1000D, not the D1000 .

Comment: Have you checked the manual?

Comment: I have tested it with sandisk 16gb class 10 , and it worked fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [official specification](http://www.canon.co.uk/For_Home/Product_Finder/Cameras/Digital_SLR/EOS_1000D/) from the Canon website says it supports SD and SDHC cards.

Not SDxc, though (which use the exFAT file system instead of FAT32 on SDHC). So as long as you stick to an SDHC card, you can use a 32GB card without any problem. The card class is only the "guaranteed supported speed" that the card supports, in reading and writing. You could go with UHS-1 if you wanted, your camera would still be fine with it. What's most likely to happen, though, is that the camera is too old to be able to write at full "Class 10" or "UHS" speeds, so the read/write speeds would be the same as if you used a Class 6, maybe.