# Why does my Canon DSLR stop recording video automatically?

Tags: canon, video, memory-card

I have read a few posts related to video recording using a DSLR so I decided to try my 60D for the first time. I've had the camera for about a year and a half but never tried recording a video.

Anyway, after a few seconds the video recording stopped and a message was displayed on the LCD screen "Recording was stopped automatically" or something like that.

Does anyone know what the problem here is? Is this SD read-write spead related?

Comment: Does the lens you're using have anything to do with it stopping?

Comment: i got a canon 60D with a Lexar class 10 sdhc 32GB, and i get this problem quite often, i heard class 10 sdhcs are not the best option for recording HD 1080 on the 60D, so im going to get a class 6 and see what results i get, i cant really understand this problem because sometimes it happens and sometimes it records with no problems.

Comment: Full memory card?

Comment: Why exactly is this on topic? How do you use this in photography? My camrea does not stop shooting photos automatically.

Comment: My 2 cents: it's on topic because if the problem really is caused by slow SD write, it would likely also affect burst mode shooting limits

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have the 60D myself, and haven't experienced this. My first guess would be the write speed of the SD-card. If the card isn't fast enough you can't record video. I can't remember the required speed, but it's  in the user manual.

Edit: Just checked the manual, and the required speed for 60D is Class 6 SD card (page 171 in the manual).

Comment: Good point. I have a few different cards so I could have been using my backup card which is not high speed. Will give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: That was it. I put in a proper card and it works fine. Thanks.

Comment: It is also worth noting that two Class 6 cards can have significant differences in performance. Some cheesy brands have cards rated at class 10 but may perform slower than a quality class 6 card. The class rating gives you an indication but don't **solely** rely on it for its true performance.

Answer (score 9):

I have had a similar experience on my Canon Rebel T2i, the recording just stopped after roughly 5 seconds or so. The reason is SD card. Though some cards say they are "class X", sometimes they don't perform at that, I would suggest following steps

1) First of all format your card once and try again. My guess is this will not help

2) Try video at a very low resolution, if it continues without any issues, it will confirm that at higher resolutions card is not able to keep up with speed of write

3) Get a Class 10 card from a good company and an authentic provider ( I own a Transcend class 10 myself and it works smoothly)

Answer (score 3):

I have also experienced this occasionally on my 60D.

Every single time it happened to me it was when I started the recording of a second clip, right after recording a pretty long first clip, so I attributed it to my SD cards not being fast enough to write whatever rest of the first clip was still in memory buffers and deal with the starting of a new clip at the same time. The SD cards that I use are the cheaper 32GB class 10 ones from Amazon, I believe the brand is Transcend. Other than this little annoyance I have no problem with these cards.

As an additional note, keep in mind that the maximum recording length on the 60D (and probably on the other Canon DSLRs as well) is 12 minutes when you record 1080p @ 24fps. When a recording reaches that length you get the same "recording was stopped automatically" message.

Comment: The limit is not 12 minutes, it is 4GB file size. Which is the file size limit for FAT32, the filesystem on memory cards. This equals to somewhere between 11:30 and approximately 15 minutes of recording time for 1080p video, depending on the dynamics of the video. Canon (and other "still camera" manufacturers) also limit the recording time to 29:59, to avoid the extra tax when importing to europe.

Answer (score 1):

To shoot video, especially HD, the card needs to be a class 6 or higher or UHS class 1 or higher. This relates to how fast the card can record information. Since video requires faster write-to-card speeds you will need these faster cards. You will see a symbol similar to this [image] (speed class) and/or this [image] (UHS speed class) somewhere on the card. The number indicates the class of the card. More information can be found [here](https://www.sdcard.org/developers/overview/speed_class/).

Answer (score 1):

It could be a card problem. I had the same problem with my canon 7D, but when I bought a faster card the problem was solved - 133X is not enough, but 266X worked well for me.

Answer (score 0):

The card is the reason. I bought a supposedly class-10 card from Amazon (Brand: AmazonBasics) and had the same problem. Now I have a SanDisk class-10 and it works perfectly.