# Shooting video on the canon 550D

Tags: canon-550d, video

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does my Canon DSLR stop recording video automatically?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/20180/why-does-canon-60d-stop-recording-automatically)

When I try to shoot video on my 550D with an 8GB memory card it will only film for a few seconds and then stops with the message that filming has stopped automatically. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue with my Canon 550D.
This seems to be a problem with the SD card sometimes. Try changing you SD card and experiment. This could also occur in combination with certain video formats.

link for similar issue

http://www.flickr.com/groups/canon_550d/discuss/72157624740483367/