# The Optimal SD Card for the Nikon D7000

Tags: nikon, nikon-d7000, sdcard, sdhc, write-speed

In my quest for new equipment I have now reached SD cards.

Now I know the Nikon D7000 supports UHS-1 *(1)* , but what is the performance gain? 
How many MB/sec does it support? I don't want to buy a 95MB/sec card if it only supports 50MB/sec.

Thanks for reading.

*(1)* Source: http://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/dslr/d7000/features03.htm

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I know what speed card to get for my camera?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/325/how-can-i-know-what-speed-card-to-get-for-my-camera)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rob Galbraith has a full spread of tests with just about every popular card for this camera. To sum up the results, the fastest card is the **SanDisk Extreme Pro 8GB SDHC card**.  It performed at 27.7MB/s JPEG and 26.4MB/s RAW for a burst of 39 shots in 30 seconds. The speed test was performed by shooting 17 JPEG Fine and then 10 NEF files.

More info can be found here: [Rob Galbraith D7000 write speed test](http://www.robgalbraith.com/bins/camera_wb_multi_page.asp?cid=6007-12454)

The "optimal" card might include price, which varies and goes out of date, so I won't comment on that here.

Comment: I use the SDXC. Just wanted to let everyone know that older SD card readers often do not recognize this card. SDHC is probably still a better choice unless you absolutely need the mammoth 64GB capacity.

Comment: my D7000 also often failed to recognize the SDHC class 10 card 16G, and SDHC class 4 4GB card.