# Panasonic FZ200 SD Card - does Class 10 UHS-I improve performance in the camera over a standard Class 10?

Tags: sdcard, panasonic, panasonic-lumix, write-speed

I was wondering if anyone has tried multiple cards in the FZ200 to find out just how fast it needs to be to make the camera as fast as possible? I bought a kit that looks like it includes a generic class 10 32GB card and I am considering buying a new one that is rated at 600x class 10 UHS-I made by transcend for about $29 USD. But if it won't make any difference besides reading it into the computer faster using a usb 3.0 card reader, I won't worry about it.

I read that some people using the high speed video modes, like 720p at 120fps had problems with it getting a write error on slower cards after about 15 seconds since the card couldn't keep up with the writing of the video, but I believe this was with a class 6 card they were trying to use. The camera users manual says it is compatible with Class 10 UHS-I, but a lot of times that just means it will work, not that it is necessarily better. It says it requires a class 4 or higher when recording motion pictures, but then I read about someone with a class 6 not being fast enough in some cases. I hope someone out there has tested some different cards and that you can help enlighten me on the subject. Maybe someone knows a place that tested different cards **in the FZ200** and you could point me in that direction.

I have found reviews on various new UHS-I cards, but that doesn't really matter since I know it doesn't need the fastest class 10 UHS-I card there is, since it says it should work with a class 4. I really just want to feel confident that I can get all of the performance out of the camera that I can without slower burst speed or getting video errors unlike people with a faster card.

Thanks

Comment: The same question has been asked for another camera make/model. See the answers to [Will a faster card increase my save speed on a Fuji S4500?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/24035/17441)

Comment: I know this same question has been answered for other cameras. I was hoping that someone with the same camera who has tried a few different cards would let me know if there is a difference before  i buy one and find out it doesn't matter at all. This is going to be different for different cameras. It will be impacted by how fast of burst speed they can do and how demanding the 1080p 60fps video recording is. Without at least having 2 different cards to test in my camera, I won't be able to figure this out on my own.