# Best memory card for my new Canon camera (700D)

Tags: dslr, memory-card, canon-700d

I just bought my first camera (Canon 700D) which got delivered to a friend who I will be visiting next week. The camera came with no memory card, so I need to buy one. I have two questions:

1. I was not able to reliably google which memory cards are supported by this camera? I can see some fairly cheap ones online, but I am not sure if they will be supported
2. Which card would you recommend? What is the minimum write speed to guarantee there will never be any problems with videos?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: This is clearly not a duplicate of the topic you suggested, question 1. is not answered there at all. Also the questions about the minimum write speed is not answered there.

Comment: Your questions would be dealt with in the camera manual.  You should download it.

Comment: Refer to Canon's support article, [What Memory Cards can be used with the camera? (EOS REBEL T5i / EOS 700D)](https://support.usa.canon.com/kb/index?page=content&id=FAQ100287&actp=search&viewlocale=en_US&searchid=1495662905819). As far as recommending cards, [shopping and product recommendations are off-topic](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3958/11924) here at Photo.SE.

Comment: You might find [this answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/46320/15871) particularly helpful. It was written much more recently than the other answers to [How can I know what speed card to get for my camera?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/325/how-can-i-know-what-speed-card-to-get-for-my-camera/46320#46320)

Answer (score 0):

I use the T5i also. When I lost my SD card, I used a slower 30Mbps one which proved to be too slow. It couldn't keep up with video recording and it took a long time to process burst shots. I upgraded to 90Mbps, which is more than fast enough and was very cheap too. However, I think only like 50mbps (class 6) is necessary to keep up with the camera.

To answer your first question, you can use SD, SDHC, or SDXC. I use a micro SD with an SD adapter, that works too. Memory is a preference. I was stuck with a 16gb card for a while which I hated because I could fill it up after just a few hundred raw photos it seemed. I use a 32gb card, which is good enough for me, but its not uncommon for photographers to prefer 64gb. Much larger cards are probably not cost efficient.

When I went to the store, the prices were confusing to me. One SD card cost $60 while another nearly identical one cost less than half as much. I asked a worker and he said it's a marketing thing. They play around the prices every so often, so while one is cheap, the other is expensive, then it might be vice versa in a few months. Assuming that the worker was telling the truth, more expensive does not necessarily mean better.

Comment: Thank you. Two questions to follow up with: 1. You mention 50mbps is class 6, but I though class 6 was 6 mbps? I think this is just confusion about how the classes are defined. 2. Is there a maximum storage capacity Canon 700D will work with? Can I safely buy 64gb? What about 128gb?